# Error with std::find

Tags: c++, std

So, I basically have this piece of code:

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;

int WpMaxSAT::findInClause(int clause, int var, ClauseType type)
{
    switch (type) {
    case SOFT:
        int val = std::find(softClauses.at(clause).begin(),
                            softClauses.at(clause).end(), var);
        break;
    case HARD:
        break;
    }

}
```

where `softClauses` is defined in the header as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> softClauses;
```

That gives me back this error:

```
wpmaxsat.cpp: In member function ‘int WpMaxSAT::findInClause(int, int, WpMaxSAT::ClauseType)’:
wpmaxsat.cpp:84:66: error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
                             softClauses.at(clause).end(), var);
```

Just to note that I am working in parallel with a friend, so the constructor is not yet defined (he is working on it). But I don't think the problem is with initialization.

I thought that this was an error with the `#include<algorithm>` line, but it looks it wans't.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `std::find`?  (e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).  In particular, the return type.

Comment: What do you want `val` to be after find? The index of the found value?

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I made the wrong assigment. I guess I should focus on the compiler errors more. The problem is that emacs was highlighting var int the function call as the "wrong" one, so I was trying to figure out what was wrong with the call and did not notice the return.

Comment: Nevermind, I was actually not really worried about the return, just wanted to know if the value existed.

Comment: @lhahn You may use `std::count` for that.

Answer (score 1):

`std::find` returns an iterator, not a value. You could read what compiler complains about and figure this out by yourself.

This how your code should be written correctly:

```
auto it = std::find(softClauses.at(clause).begin(),
                    softClauses.at(clause).end(), var);

if (it != softClauses.at(clause).end()) {
    int val = *it;
}
```

If you only want to know is the value `var` exists in the `vector`, you may use [std::count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/) for this. It does not return an iterator but a some type `InputIterator::difference_type` which is:

> Signed integral type

I'd treat it as `size_t` as it is usual for `STL` containers.
Use of `std::count` is simple:

```
auto count = std::count(softClauses.at(clause).begin(),
                        softClauses.at(clause).end(), var);

if (count) {
    // value exists here
}
```

Comment: There are (at least) two problems here.  1. As Victor Polevoy noted, ``std::find`` returns an iterator, not a value. 2. You're applying ``find`` on iterators of a ``std::vector<std::vector<int>>``, but are looking for an ``int``. That's not how ``std::find`` works. You basically look for some `Foo` object in a range of `Foo` objects (note same type).